# what is the best way to create javascript menu?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way or an easy way to create a javascript menu. When I say best, I mean there are many softwares that help in creating menus, for eg. Sothink DHTML menu. Isnt there a menu control available in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript is language, it doesn't have any built in "menu" support. What kind of menu are you looking for? Be more specific and people here can recommend on reliable and nice looking stuff.

Comment: See also previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177888/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-javascript-menu-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to buy or even just install a program solely for the purpose of constructing a JavaScript menu.

First of all, the menu itself should not contain any JavaScript code. It should just be a nested list. You shouldn't need a program to write that code for you. If you do, then you're probably using a WYSIWYG editor anyways, and any WYSIWYG HTML editor will create an unordered list for you.

Once you've created the menu structure, you just need to add the display style and behavior to make it look/behave like a dropdown or flyout menu. This can be done either in pure CSS or with CSS + JavaScript. Some people prefer to use JavaScript to turn a regular list into a dropdown/flyout menu because they think using `display: none` is bad for SEO, and if you style items like that to begin with, then people without JavaScript will not be able to see the hidden menu items. However, there are ways around both of those problems using pure CSS.

If you're using jQuery, then there are a number of jQuery plugins that let you create your menus with just 1-2 lines of code. Otherwise, there are standalone scripts and that can do the same.

Comment: @Chandan: It looks like a desktop program that lets you build menus visually and generates the code for you. It's pretty useless and completely unnecessary in most workflows.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177888/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-javascript-menu-closed

You just asked this question a couple of minutes ago?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.webanddesigners.com/33-jquery-tutorials-to-create-navigation-menu) is JQuery cool menus that you can reference.Anyway Javascript is client side script language.There is no control at all.